# WebApi action method returning null

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

It's been a whole day and I can't able to find a solution.
My Controller's ActionMethod is working fine when it calls from PostMan.
But when I call it from my Unit Test Method, it keeps returning null.

Here is my code.
I already found an answer on StackOverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56498657/11425180

But this is not resolving my issue.

Here is my ActionMethod

```
[HttpPost("register")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterUser([FromBody] CreateUserRequest request)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            try
            {
                //  Map request with dto and give to service
                CreateUserRequestDto createDto = _mapper.Map<CreateUserRequestDto>(request);
                CreateUserResponseDto response = await _userService.CreateUser(createDto);

                if (response.IsSuccess)
                {
                    Success success = new Success(message: SuccessMessages.UserCreated, data: response);
                    return Ok(success);
                }

                Error error = new Error(message: ErrorMessages.UserRegistrationFailed, description: response.Error.Description);
                return BadRequest(error);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return HandleException(ex);
            }
        }
```

Here is my test Class

```
    public class MockAccountControllerTests
    {
        readonly UserController _accountController;

        public MockAccountControllerTests()
        {
            Mock<IMapper> _mockMapper = new Mock<IMapper>();
            Mockers.InitializeMappers(_mockMapper);
            UserManager<AppUser> _mockUserManager = Mockers.MockUserManager<AppUser>().Object;
            UserRepository _mockUserRepository = new Mock<UserRepository>(_mockUserManager, _mockMapper.Object).Object;
            UserService _mockUserService = new Mock<UserService>(_mockUserRepository).Object;

            _accountController = new Mock<UserController>(_mockUserService, _mockMapper.Object).Object;
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task RegisterUser_NullUserNamePassword_ThrowsException()
        {
            CreateUserRequest request = RequestHelpers.CreateUserRequest(null, null);

            IActionResult result = await _accountController.RegisterUser(request);

            ObjectResult badRequest = result as ObjectResult;

            Assert.NotNull(badRequest);
            Assert.True(badRequest is BadRequestObjectResult);
            Assert.Equal(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, badRequest.StatusCode);
            Assert.NotNull(badRequest.Value);
            Assert.IsType<Error>(badRequest.Value);
        }
    }
```

At this line in my Test Method

```
var result = await _accountController.RegisterUser(request);
```

The `result` is `null`

I also tried to assign a value of `BadRequest` to a variable like this

`var a = BadRequest("Test Message");`
The `a` is also `null` in this case.

How this will be corrected?
Am I doing something wrong in my ActionMethod or TestMethod?
Kindly review.

Comment: Read [ask] and provide a [mre]. How do you initialize your `_accountController`? What does `HandleException()` return? Have you tried debugging your test and stepping through your code?

Comment: What is the value of `result.GetType` (check in the `Immediate Window`)?

Comment: Listen buddy, if `await _accountController.RegisterUser(request)` returns `null`, then the problem is in your code. In a unit test, a lot of the ASP.NET plumbing is simply not running, so it is not comparable to issuing a request with PostMan to your running API. So again: show how you initialize `_accountController`, and step through its code to see where `null` is returned.  I'm not being clever, I'm telling you from years of experience of building and testing in ASP.NET (MVC (Core)) that the problem is in your code.

Comment: @CodeCaster If you thing that there is a problem in my _accountController,
I am simply Mocking AccountController

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised, for example, if your `_accountController` is initialized by a `new Mock<AccountController>().Object`, because `BadRequest()` will never return `null`. Testing a mock is the wrong approach, you mock dependencies, not the system under test. So stop fighting with me in comments, and [edit] your question show your entire test class.

Comment: @ArslanMunir the moral of this is that if you do not show us the whole picture in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then you end up wasting the time of those volunteering to help you solve **your** problem, with needless back and forth.

Comment: I am getting this exact scenario.   The question is straight forward.

When I resolve the result which I passed a string that does actually work to the API,  the Unit test is simply returning NULL for result.Value   which I am expecting a string (not the type that the response was, not sure how this is relevant)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is the culprit:

```
 _accountController = new Mock<UserController>(_mockUserService, _mockMapper.Object).Object;
```

Don't mock your system under test, because then you're not testing your code, but simply whether Moq does what it's supposed to do. And it does: it returns default values (`null` for reference types) for method calls that aren't `SetUp()`.

So instead initialize it to an actual instance of your controller:

```
 _accountController = new UserController(_mockUserService, _mockMapper.Object);
```

See also: [Test controller logic in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/testing?view=aspnetcore-2.2) on learn.microsoft.com.

Answer (score -1):

The only possible explanation is that whatever the type of `result`, it's not derived from `ObjectResult`, so casting it to `ObjectResult` via `as` results in a null value being returned.

The thing is that, I don't see any output that returns something that doesn't derive from `ObjectResult`, except in your catch block where you're returning `HandleException(ex)`. It's not clear *what* the type returned is here, so I can only assume that that's where your problem lies. In short, that needs to return an `ObjectResult` type. Things like `BadRequestResult` without `Object` in their names derive from `StatusCodeResult`, which shares no lineage with `ObjectResult`.

It's also worth mentioning that once you get past this assertion, your next will fail. Since you're casting whatever the result is to `ObjectResult` and saving it to `badRequest`, the assertion `Assert.True(badRequest is BadRequestObjectResult)` will always fail, because it will always be `ObjectResult`, not `BadRequestObjectResult`.